# Best "For Pay" wpf controls

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, controls

If this question has been asked then I applogize and I will join in voting to close it (or just delete it), but I could not find it being asked before.

We are potentially embarking on making many of our apps using WPF.  Most of our apps are normal business apps that will not need too much eye candy.  Tasteful ui is nice, but I don't see us doing lost of custom animations and such.

So, my question is what 3rd party control sets are the best ones to purchase to save you time in development of apps like this?

(These should work with both Visual Studio 2008 and 2010.)

Comment: As this is "poll" type question you might want to make it "community wiki" to avoid it being closed immediately.

Comment: how do you make something community wiki?

Comment: nevermind just saw the checkbox :P

Comment: What are you looking for? Edit controls, data grids? Performance, ease of development? Good customer service?

Comment: @Rob Fonseca-Ensor - Ease of development would be my #1 on that list.  We would need edit controls and a datagrid.

Answer (score 1):

We use Telerik in the shop I work for

Comment: Do you like them?  Do they save you time or improve your apps?

Comment: I like them, we also are using infragistics, we have both.  when we got the telerik, we also got the source code. makes it nice, we can fix bugs, etc. as we find them.  also, the telerik has silverlight controls as well.

Answer (score 1):

We use [Infragistics WPF Controls](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/wpf.aspx#Overview) they save us a lot of time and they are very extendible. As well as very well documented with examples.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit tangential to the main question, but if you have the budget and your main goal is a slick, tasteful UI, you may want to experiment with hiring a graphic designer (with experience in business-app WPF UIs, preferably) to work with your team.  Because WPF enables a much cleaner separation of logic and visuals, with control and data templates, you can put together your application using the 'basic' controls set and have your graphic designer polish the look and feel.

Comment: While I agree with this, getting a new position approved is very different than getting a tool set approved.  It would not get into the budget.